# Reversal of Array in C Using Given Array

Tags: c, arrays, linux

I am having trouble implementing a reversal of an array in C. I am using linux/nano and we have just started, so very minimal has been taught. The code below is what I have, and the array will print of the binary numbers of whatever integer is entered, but in this code, the binary is reversed from what it should be.

```
#include "stdio.h"

#define MAX_BITS 32

 int main()
 {
        int num;
        printf("Enter a valid positive integer: ");
        scanf("%d", &num);

        int array[MAX_BITS];
        int bit, val;
        int numDown = 1;
 while (numDown <= num)
 {
      val = numDown;

      while (val > 0)
      {
          bit = val % 2; 
          printf("%d",bit);
          val = val / 2;
      }

          printf("\n");
          numDown = numDown + 1;

    }

    return 0;

}
```

I know I need a while loop but I am unsure as to how to go about it.

Comment: What has your uninitialized array to do with your `while` loop? I don't get your question.

Comment: This code was mostly given to me already and It prints out the binary representation of every number previous. So If I entered 13, it would print out every number before 13 in binary, only thing is is that it is backwards.

Comment: I know what the loop does, but I see no correlation between the code and your question. You ask *Reversal of Array in C Using Given Array* but you never use the array. So what is your real question?

Comment: I was given this MAX_BITS array that holds 32, and using that, I have to set a number in the array and then reverse it so it prints out backwards essentially, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Use two `while()` loops, e.g., `numDown = 1; while (numDown < num && numDown < (1 << (MAX_BITS-1))) { numDown <<= 1; } while (numDown > 0) { printf((num & numDown) ? '1' : '0'); numDown >>= 1; }`

Comment: You're not using your array for anything, which is probably a big clue how to do this with mostly the code you already have.

Comment: Thank you, where in the code would i implement the while loops? after val = numDown?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_BITS 32
int main()
{
    int num;
    printf("Enter a valid positive integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    char array[MAX_BITS];
    int index = MAX_BITS - 1;
    int temp = num;
    do
    {
        array[index--] = temp % 2;
        temp /= 2;
    }while(temp != 0);
    printf("Binary of %d is: ", num);
    for (int i = index + 1; i < MAX_BITS; ++i )
    {
        printf("%d", array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```